# Is there a way to generate a login token for a Magento admin_user?

Tags: magento

We have merchants logged in to a system, from which we want to link them to our Magento instance with some kind of admin token that will log them in directly without them having to manually login.

I see the `rp_token` field in the `admin_user` table but that appears to be related to a password reset, which probably isn't what we want.

Have done a bit of searching, found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745464/linking-to-magento-admin-from-outside-admin-panel) which is related but is dealing with secret keys specifically (which will probably be my second challenge to resolve after resolving this one).

I'm guessing this isn't supported in core, but maybe there's a good extension out there to do it?

Or if not, what would be the best approach to implement?  I'm guessing there is probably an event I could hook to look at a GET or POST param (which maybe could be a hash of the username and hashed password), then bypass the normal login() method which relies on username and plain text password.

That feels like it could be a little risky though?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That feels like it could be a little risky though? Any thoughts?

This is extremely risky, but it can be done safely. I can speak on a similar issue I had in developing QuarkBar, an administration bar for Magento that is set to release this weekend.

So to show the bar, I need to verify the admin is logged in. Unfortunately that's hard to do on the frontend module, since there are two separate sessions. So to get around that I've created a `quarkbar_session` table. I use OpenSSL to store a secure crypt key once an admin is logged in, that I then check for on each request and match it to a cookie. If it matches, the admin is verified.

It's a little different from what you want of course, since I first set the key when the admin is logged in (it's an observer event). But it should get you started.

Source (NOT ready for production, use it for ideas): https://github.com/zschuessler/QuarkBar/tree/master/app/code/community/Zaclee/QuarkBar

Also, note that I'm storing the secure key so that I can access the admin backend. The solutions in your link say to disable it. You don't have to, check out QuarkBar for implementation.

Comment: Brilliant.  And actually this works for my workflow as well, because there will be an initial login upon account registration where we can hook the login_success event.

Comment: Great! I forgot to add, *only* use the cookie for acting as a flag. Never store any confidential data in the cookie. Be as paranoid as possible when making your implementation.